# What are the stokes parameters of a linear wave added to a circular one?

Tags: electromagnetism, optics, electromagnetic-radiation, polarization, plane-wave

So consider the following thing: Let's suppose that we have a situation with two monochromatic waves propagating through the z-axis. Both waves have the same frequency and intensity. How can I find the Stokes parameter of this superposition?

I'm stuck because I don't know how to start this. As we have two haves, I think I have to let the Stokes parameters as a function of the phase shift between the two waves, but I didn't have any progress thinking this way.

Comment: Could you include the Stokes parameters of the 2 waves?

Answer (score 1):

Superpositions are easier to tackle using Jones vectors. If we write the electric field as $\mathbf{E}=\alpha \mathbf{x}+\beta\mathbf{y}$, we can express it as a vector
$$\mathbf{E}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha\\\beta\end{pmatrix}.$$ Superpositions of two vectors can be computed using regular vector addition
$$\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}=\mathbf{E}_{1}+\mathbf{E}_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1+\alpha_2\\\beta_1+\beta_2\end{pmatrix}.$$ If you have a phase shift, like you mentioned, that can be explicitly put in via
$$\mathbf{E}_{1}+e^{i\phi}\mathbf{E}_{2}=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_1+e^{i\phi}\alpha_2\\\beta_1+e^{i\phi}\beta_2\end{pmatrix}.$$

Linear waves, circular waves, etc have well-known Jones vectors. For example, horizontally polarized light can be represented by $$\mathbf{E}_{h}=\begin{pmatrix}1\\0\end{pmatrix}.$$

The Stokes parameters can be directly calculated from the Jones vector by using the Pauli matrices $\sigma_\mu$. The relationship looks like \begin{aligned}
S_0&=\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}^\dagger\sigma_0 \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}
\\
S_1&=\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}^\dagger\sigma_3 \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}\\
S_2&=\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}^\dagger\sigma_1 \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}\\
S_3&=\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}^\dagger\sigma_2 \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}},\end{aligned} where $^\dagger$ means the Hermitian conjugate (take the transpose and the complex conjugate).

---

One can probably imagine that choosing a different basis in which to express $\mathbf{E}$ leads to a more compact expression for the Stokes parameters in terms of the Pauli matrices: using the circular basis $\mathbf{l}=(\mathbf{x}+i\mathbf{y})/\sqrt{2}$ and $\mathbf{r}=(\mathbf{x}-i\mathbf{y})/\sqrt{2}$ to write the electric field $\mathbf{E}^{(\mathrm{circular\,basis})}$ yields the Stokes parameters
$$S_\mu=\mathbf{E}^{(\mathrm{circular\,basis})\,\dagger}\sigma_\mu \mathbf{E}^{(\mathrm{circular\,basis})},\qquad \mu\in(0,1,2,3).$$

Comment: well, I'm able to write the Jones vectors for my case. But can you elaborate on the conversion between Jones vectors and Stokes parameters? I would not mind if you just do a reference. I'm searching here but I'm not finding anything like you pointed out.

Comment: Ah right I defined the Stokes parameters slightly differently following the quantum mechanical convention that uses the circular coordinates (the $l,r$ basis here https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters#Representations_in_fixed_bases) so that the indices of the Stokes parameters and the Pauli matrices match (eg https://doi.org/10.1364/AOP.404175).

Comment: If we take the Wiki convention using the $x,y$ basis https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stokes_parameters#Representations_in_fixed_bases then we get $I=|E_x|^2+|E_y|^2=\mathbf{E}^\dagger \sigma_0\mathbf{E}$, where $\sigma_0$ is the $2\times 2$ identity matrix. We would find $Q=|E_x|^2-|E_y|^2=\mathbf{E}^\dagger \sigma_3\mathbf{E}$, where $\sigma_3$ is the third Pauli matrix. Similarly, they have $U=\mathbf{E}^\dagger \sigma_1\mathbf{E}$, and $V=\mathbf{E}^\dagger \sigma_2\mathbf{E}$. This means that the conventional $(S_1,S_2,S_3)=(Q,U,V)$ uses the Pauli matrices $(\sigma_3,\sigma_1,\sigma_2)$

Comment: The edits should clear things up

Comment: Hey man! Your edit really helped me out! But let me tell you a thing. I know the values of the stokes parameters I'm trying to find. And using your formula Is giving me twice this value. In no way could we have $2U = E^{†}\sigma_1 E$, for example. Right?

Comment: [Here is the math fo Q with you wanna check](https://imgur.com/1dbXqbK)

Comment: This should work out but it will all depend on normalization. In my convention, I'm saying $I=|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2$, but you could define everything with another proportionality constant. Perhaps you are looking for the normalized Stokes parameters $(S_1,S_2,S_3)/S_0$? Equivalently, perhaps you want to first normalize your field by $\sqrt{|\alpha|^2+|\beta|^2}$? Either way will yield consistent results - in quantum optics we like to add a normalization factor of $1/2$ to help out with commutation rules.

Comment: Well. What I did was to use the normalized Jones vector to each case of my waves, and multiply them by the amplitude and phase I needed. But I did not normalize the resultant Jones vector. Well, I'll try to figure it out.

Comment: Well. I calculate all the parameters using the Jones vectors. They satisfy $I^2=Q^2+U^2+V^2$ as well the ones that I have here. I totally agree with you that this difference is related to the normalization, but until now I haven't found where the difference arises.

Comment: Great. There could be normalizations in your superposition of two waves: some people might add two waves so sum the two electric fields, while others may say that they have a normalized superposition, so right away they might write $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{total}}=(\mathbf{E}_1+\mathbf{E}_2)/\sqrt{2}$ or something (the normalization constant there will probably have to depend upon the overlap $\mathbf{E}_1^\dagger \mathbf{E}_2$).